# Preventing GridView from adding redundant rows

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have the following code:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form1.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {

            int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
            }
```

So I copy rows which were selected in a GridView to another Gridview. Now I want him to check if a row is already added to the second one and open a messagebox. How to do that? I haven't found solutions which fit in my case.

Comment: in dataGridView, make first column as unique by storing first column value in List collection. If value is already exist dont add that row values...

Comment: Isn't there a better way? maybe just an IF-ELSE statement?

Comment: Another you have to iterate full dataGridview2 to check if Row value is already exist or not?

Comment: Yes. How to do that? Thats the problem I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form1.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            bool isnotexist = true;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rowgrid2 in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (rowgrid2.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                {
                    isnotexist = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isnotexist)
            {
                int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this code help...

Comment: Something is wrong. Either he copies no rows or he copies wrong ones.

Comment: Sorry I now realized that. I have no primary key so cells can have the same values. He just checks the first column and leaves rows out where the value of the first column is the same. Is there a way to let him check every single cell value in a row and drop the row if it's COMPLETELY identical?

Comment: You want check all cells in a row?

Comment: Exactly. It should drop the row when every Cell is identical, so the row is 1:1 the same. He should take the row if minimum one Cell has a different value. I tried this with counting the columns and then replace the "[0]" with the count variable-1 but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: **foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in rowgrid2.Cells)** put inside of **foreach (DataGridViewRow rowgrid2 in dataGridView2.Rows)** loop.. You can iterate through all cell without counting cells...

Comment: He can't find "dataGridView2.Cells". And when I change it to rowgrid2.Cells" he can't find "rowgrid2"

Comment: Ok I took your example and solved it with a "for"-loop. Thanks!